# Unable to read special characters written in a file uploaded to s3 using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker

The issue facing here was had a file in s3 with special characters in the file content. while trying to download the file from s3 using java code, The special characters(ä,ü) are getting replaced with empty spaces while reading/writing the content to the file.

I tried Multiple patterns to read the file using UTF-8 format to support special characters but nothing worked out (using BufferedReader,BufferedWriter,FileReader,FileWriter,InputStream,OutputStream etc...)

```
String uploadPath = /u01/infor/sce/scp11/logs/temp.sql
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
S3Object obj = s3Client.getObject(System.getenv("BUCKET"), "/temp.sql");
S3ObjectInputStream s3ObjectInputStream = obj.response().asInputStream();

// Download the file content to a local file
String localFilePath = uploadPath;
try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(localFilePath)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = s3ObjectInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    System.out.println("File downloaded successfully.");
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.info("Error while downloading sql file from s3"+e.getMessage(),e);
}
```

Working Python code

```
import io
import json
import boto3
import botocore
import datetime
import base64
import os
import random
import string
import time


s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

#obj = s3.Object('hg-us-east-1', 'key-to-file.json')

s3_object = boto3.resource('s3').Object('hg-us-east-1', 'logs/delete-entries.sql')
data = io.BytesIO()
s3_object.download_fileobj(data)
s = None
b = s3_object.get()['Body']
s = b.read().decode('utf-8')
#result = json.loads(s)
print(s);
f = open("c:\\Users\\tim\\test.sql", "w")
f.write(s);
```

JAVA CODE used for reading the file
After downloading file from s3 i was using the following java code to read the sql file that was downloaded from s3.

when reading the file inside the docker container the special characters are getting replaced with empty spaces.

i can confirm no issues while downloading file from s3..It's all about reading downloaded file through java code that wasn't happening correctly

```
public static ArrayList<String> Parser(String sqlfile,String user) {
        ArrayList<String> statements = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader reader=null;
        try {
            reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(sqlfile), "UTF-8"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            log.info("PARSE_PRINTING"+line);
            while (line != null) {
                line = line.trim();
                if (line.startsWith("--") || line.equals("")) {

                } else if (line.startsWith("/*")) {
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null && !s.endsWith("*/")) {

                    }
                } else {

                    if (line.endsWith(";")) {
                        statements.add(line);
                    } else {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line);
                        String s = "";
                        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(" ").append(s);
                            if (s.endsWith(";"))
                                break;
                        }
                        statements.add(sb.toString());
                        System.out.println("LINE" + line);
                    }
                }
                line = reader.readLine();
                log.info("PARSE_PRINTING"+line);
            }
            int count = 0;
            for (String test : statements) {
                log.info("STATEMENT " + test);
                count++;
            }
            log.info("Total No Of SQL STATEMENTS " + count);
            return statements;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printstacktrace();
        }
        return statements;
    }
```

Comment: You unfortunately just show code which should copy the file as is to local storage. Any problems will occur after that. What is your OS?

Comment: The following [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_GetObject_section.html) is using the latest version of the SDK and another set of APIs (basically you get directly a byte array and skip the stream part), give it a try.

Comment: @g00se it was linux

Comment: Right. You need to show the code where the problem occurs

Comment: The problem was occuring here ...S3Object obj = s3Client.getObject(System.getenv("BUCKET"), "/temp.sql");

Comment: The python code that i added was working i mean i am able to get data and able to write data into a file including special characters...but that doesn't happening with java code.

Comment: The Java code does quite a different thing. It makes a literal copy of the file. No decoding involved. The Python decodes it as UTF-8. *At what point do you notice a problem and what **exactly** do you do to see it?*

Comment: When getting file from s3 i had issue ..when java code tries to pull the file from s3 that's where it was getting completely messed up....S3ObjectInputStream s3ObjectInputStream = obj.response().asInputStream();

Comment: Sorry but you didn't answer my question

Comment: g00se the issue here was while i was executing the java  code inside a docker container.... the java code that i had was unable to read special characters in a file.

Comment: Well, the error will be almost certainly in Java code that you didn't post, since, as I mentioned, your posted code makes a literal copy of the stream

Comment: updated my javacode that i sued for reading the downloaded file..this works fine when i was executing locally on my laptop when i deploy the code to the container the issue arises

Comment: *It's all about reading downloaded file through java code that wasn't happening correctly* That's too general to help I'm afraid. It's worth observing that your assumption that the file is encoded as UTF-8 should be checked. I suppose if the Python code is operating on the same file and working, then your assumption could be correct. If it's your logging statements (including sysouts) that are bothering you, then they can probably be ignored

Comment: g00se i was trying to say that the code was working fine when executed locally on my machine when the same code was deployed to container it was unable to read special characters from a file